# RabbitMQ new consumer hangs

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm using rabbitmq 3.6.6 using the docker image "rabbitmq:3"

Whenever I add a new consumer to my RabbitMQ queue it hangs from anywhere to 10 seconds 10 hours.

Below is an example of code used to get the error. I also get this error in Go. So it's not library dependant.

```
<?php

include(__DIR__."/vendor/autoload.php");
print "Start" . PHP_EOL;
$connection = new \PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection('xxxx', 5697, 'guest', 'guest');
$channel = $connection->channel();

$callback = function($msg) {
  echo " [x] Received ", $msg->body, "\n";
};

$channel->basic_consume('repositories', '', false, false, false, false, $callback);

while(count($channel->callbacks)) {
    $channel->wait();
}
```

When I look at the logs I see

```
=INFO REPORT==== 31-Jan-2017::21:14:33 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.891.0> (10.32.0.1:54216 -> 10.44.0.3:5672)
=INFO REPORT==== 31-Jan-2017::21:14:34 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.902.0> (10.32.0.1:54247 -> 10.44.0.3:5672)
```

When I do list_consumer during via rabbitmqctl I see the consumer in the list, yet no messages are processed by it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I needed to set the Qos setting.

Some more information can be found at:

- http://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html
- https://github.com/streadway/amqp/blob/master/channel.go#L576